# Is there a way to eliminate options when quantity hits 0?

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm building a form that involves class times. When a certain class time his `0`, will that option disappear, or is it going to be up there even if the quantity is empty?

For example, if this class time hits `0`, will it still be in the drop down?:

[image: Forms example]

It's been pain point with our last product to have those options still in there. Some classes can have almost 20 options! It will be a pain for our clients to have to select each option to see if it's filled or not.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) will limit quantities for choices but will not disable or hide choices that are no longer valid.  We just released this feature a few weeks ago and are listening to feedback from our customers on how to improve this to better meet your needs.

Please [submit a feature request](https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/) detailing what types of changes would enhance your use of [quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/quantity-limits).